# Static collection shared between multiple threads behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

For the below code snippet:

```
public class ThreadExample extends Thread {

    static List<Integer> myList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        myList.add(11);
        myList.add(22);
        myList.add(33);
        myList.add(44);
        ThreadExample e = new ThreadExample();
        e.start();
        for (Integer it : myList) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.print("e1 ");
            }
            System.out.print(" " + it);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("e2 ");
        }
        myList.add(77);
        System.out.print("size: " + myList.size() + ", elements:");
    }
}
```

The code always prints output as :
size: 5, elements: 11 22 33 44

I am not able to understand this behavior. When the worker thread is modifying the static list by adding a new element for which the size is reflected properly then why does the main thread prints only 4 elements? Given that the worker thread is executed first always(sleep time is less there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `CopyOnWriteArrayList` gives you thread-safe iterators, in that you can iterate the list while it is being concurrently modified, without throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

*Logically* (not actually, because this is inefficient and not thread-safe), iterating a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is like this:

```
List<Integer> copyOfList = new ArrayList<>(myList);
for (Integer it : copyOfList) {
  // ...
}
```

If any update to the list occurs during iteration, it doesn't matter: you're iterating a "copy" of the list at the start of the iteration.

You sleep briefly in the thread before adding the element; but by that time, the main thread has already started iterating the list.

Since the list initially has 4 elements, and the iteration of the list starts before the thread adds the element, your loop will print out 4 elements.

Comment: That makes sense, when I moved the myList.add(77) to the start of run() I started seeing all the elements in the list by main thread.

Answer (score 2):

That's because in your `for (Integer it : myList)` you're creating an `Iterator` over the `CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>` and from the Java doc:

> The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a reference to the state of
>   the array at the point that the iterator was created. This array never
>   changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is
>   impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException. The iterator will not reflect
>   additions, removals, or changes to the list since the iterator was
>   created.

So the main thread won't see the update from the `e` thread because **in most cases** ( you've a sleep in the `run()` method) the `Iterator` is created before the `e` thread adds a new `Integer`.

Further info [at the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).